# Node.js DNS Lookup scope error? (POST request)

Tags: node.js, express, post, dns, response

I'm making a DNS Lookup API using Node.js and Express.js framework such that when it sends a POST request, it should return the addresses of different record types.

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  // Request format
  // const l = {
  //   lookup: 'twitter.com',
  //   recordTypes: ['A', 'TXT']
  // };

  // Using destructor to fetch properties
  const { lookup, recordTypes } = req.body;
  console.log(lookup, recordTypes);

  // For each record type
  recordTypes.forEach(function(type) {
    // setTimeout to get something async
    setTimeout(function() {
      dns.resolve(lookup.toLowerCase(), type, (err, addresses) => {
        console.log(type);
        if (err) {
          return console.log(`\nType(${type}):\n`, err);
        }
        result = result + JSON.stringify({ type: `${type}`, response: { addresses } });
        console.log(result);
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
  res.send(result);
});
```

It logs the correct stuff in the console but when it comes to the response, it returns an empty string. I used setTimeout to mimic the asynchronous nature of the request but it just does not work.

Please assume that I have declared stuff like result etc. because it is working. Also, please don't to redirect me to the Node.js documentation because I have already read that stuff and that's not the problem here. The problem is that I need to get every record type in an array and send that back as a response.

Here's what I have tried:

- Tried to push response for each record type in the result array,
- Tried to use a for of loop instead of forEach

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'm reading your code is that for each item in the array you correctly use callbacks to do each individual bit of processing.

However, remember that `forEach` itself is not asynchronous. Thus you are setting up a bunch of tasks that will complete sometime, then returning `undefined`... then your results start to trickle in.

There's a couple ways to correctly. As you are using callbacks here I will use that style. You want to get a callback when all items in an array have been completely processed. The [async module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) does this very well, providing a lot of high quality methods that act on arrays and such and give you a way to have a callback when they are all over.

Your function will look something like:

```
 let res = []

 async.each( recordTypes,
    ( type, done ) => {
      dns.resolve(lookup.toLowerCase(), type, (err, addresses) => {
        result = result + JSON.stringify({ type: `${type}`, response: { addresses } });
        done(err)
      } )
    },
    (allOverError) => {
      res.send(result);
    }
)
```

Notice there are two function parameters here: the first one is called for every item in the list, and the last is called when every item in the list has been completely processed.

There are other ways too, promises or the async/await keywords (confusing because of the name of the async module), but callbacks are good.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I thought it would work but the error I'm getting is : "types is not defined" which basically means that for some reason it is not parsing through the recordTypes. 
Do you think there's a way out of that? I have never used this module and I really think that it can be of great help!

Comment: Ahh yes, I updated the code. I misunderstood where things were coming from ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D
I have to tweak the code a bit but it worked.

Comment: Hi!
I tried putting if-else statements in the second parameter because I need that but once it enters an if block, it just completely ends and sends the incomplete response. Do you know how to rectify that?